# Line Tangent to Two Non-Equal Circles on a 2D Plane

Tags: geometry, circles, applications, tangent-line

If I have two circles, say Circle A is on the origin of a cartesian plane and Circle B is placed at a point with a known horizontal and vertical distance from the origin. The diameters of both circles is known. A line is drawn such that is tangent with both Circles A and B.

A line is drawn from the Origin of Circle B to its point of tangency.

Is there a way to determine (in a general case) the angle between this line and the vertical axis?

[image]

Comment: Note that in general, there are four distinct lines tangent to both cirlces, with four distinct gradients (two of these tangents cross over between the circles).

Comment: Your text isn't clear. Please confirm for example that circles $A$ and $B$ are in horizontal planes.

Comment: @JeanMarie - Yes, both circles are on a 2D plane.

Comment: Couldn't you explain your problem by using the term "cone" ?

Comment: @TonyK - Sorry, I'm not following. Are you referring lines originating at each circles center and tangent to the other circle and two lines tangent to both circles?

Comment: @JeanMarie - How do you mean? I do not think so. These are two circles of known diameters and locations on a 2D plane. A cone defines a 3D shape; does it not?

Comment: No I'm not, Thirsty. I think my comment is clear. (For instance, one of these four tangents is horizontal in your diagram.)

Comment: @TonyK - That is only a graphical illusion. "h" could be such that a horizontal line is not tangent to both circles.

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. I'm just trying to get you to see the tangent that I'm talking about. You do see it, right?

Comment: If the circles are far enough, you can get 4 tangents. See for example https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/CommonTangents.gif So that means that you would get 4 angles

Comment: @Andrei - Yes, I see the lines; they are the root of what I am attempting to define. I suppose because I am not a mathematician, I am struggling to correctly ask my question; so I will try it this way: In the absence of drawing a diagram on a piece of paper, how would mathematically correlate the tangent lines to the circles?

Comment: The question is CLEAR! Note that the radiuses to the tangent are perpendicular. You get a trapezoid. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Moti - Yes; thank you! I just figured it out!